# Retrieve messages from app like trello in real time - Slack

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm using slack API to retrieve messages from bot app (like trello in slack.com). I used this API `https://slack.com/api/im.history`. But my goal, is to get messages from that bot app in real time to my application without reloading page. I already read the [RTM API docs](https://api.slack.com/rtm), and also [The events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api). I didn't figure out how to do so. What should I do ?

Here is server/main.js :

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';

import '../imports/api/messages.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  Meteor.methods({
    checkSlack() {
      this.unblock();
      try {
        var result = HTTP.call('GET','https://slack.com/api/im.history', {
          params: {
            token: 'xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            channel: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
          }
        });
        return result.data.messages;
      } catch (error) {
        // Got a network error, timeout, or HTTP error in the 400 or 500 range.
        return error.message;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

imports/api/messages.js:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Messages = new Mongo.Collection('messages');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // This code only runs on the server
  Meteor.publish('messages', function messagesPublication() {
    return Messages.find();
  });
}
```

imports/ui/Message.jsx:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class Message extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li>{this.props.message.text}</li>
    );
  }
}

Message.propTypes = {
  message: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

imports/ui/App.jsx:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import { Messages } from '../api/messages.js';

import Message from './Message.jsx';

const _ = require('lodash');

// App component - represents the whole app
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
    };
    this.renderMessages = this.renderMessages.bind(this);
    this.getMessages = this.getMessages.bind(this);
    this.saveMessages = this.saveMessages.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMessages();
  }

  getMessages() {
     const handle = this;
     Meteor.call('checkSlack',function(err, response) {
        if(err){
          console.log('error');
        }
        else {
          handle.setState({
            messages: response,
          });
        }
     });
  };

  renderMessages() {
     const messages = Messages.find({}).fetch();
     return messages.map((message, index) => (
       <Message key={index} message={message} />
     ));
 }

  saveMessages(){    
    const messages = this.state.messages;
    const msgs = Messages.find({}).fetch();
    var addedMsgs = _.differenceBy(messages,msgs, 'ts');
     _.map(addedMsgs, (message) =>
      Messages.insert(message)
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Messages List</h1>
        </header>
        <button onClick={this.saveMessages}>Save</button>
        {this.renderMessages()}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

App.propTypes = {
  messages: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('messages');
  return {
    messages: Messages.find({}).fetch(),
  };
}, App);
```

client/main.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from '../imports/ui/App.jsx';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('render-target'));
});
```

client/main.html:

```
<head>
  <title>App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="render-target"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the Slack events coming through from the API, to a Meteor server, simply insert them into a Mongo collection, and then set up your Meteor client to subscribe to the database, and you will have a real time feed to your UI

**UPDATE**

Thanks for possting your code, now I can see what's going on.

1) In your server code you are doing this:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  Meteor.methods({
```

It probably works OK, but these are independent things. Meteor methods often lives in another file, and is just used to declare your methods.

2) You only save the messages to the collection from the UI. They need to be inserted when you get them in the server method - then your publication and subscription will work

3) Remove the call to checkSlack from componentDidMount, and put it in the server startup.

4) Your http request to slack will only retrieve the history, you need to get more sophisticated here. Read https://api.slack.com/rtm for how you can open a socket and get a real time feed

Comment: I've already inserted them in collection after they show up in UI. Subribe won't make a difference. In imports/api/messages.js                                     
export const Messages = new Mongo.Collection('messages');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // This code only runs on the server
  Meteor.publish('messages', function messagesPublication() {
    return Messages.find();
  });    In ui/App.jsx: export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('messages');
  return {
    messages: Messages.find({}).fetch(),
  };
}, App);

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I want to get messages in real time, that means when I send a message to bot app (like trello) it will send to my UI without reloading the page.

Comment: If you have your publication/subscription set up properly it should do just that. The code in your comment isn't readable - can you edit your question and put it in there, and format the block using the {} button. Thanks